# PHP_verify function and how do i get it to verify with my code?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So yesterday i asked on here why wasn't my code of creating a password_hash() not working and i finally got it working after some help from some users (GREATLY APPRECIATED!!) and now my next situation is verifying it with password_verify(). Below is my code,can you tell me what i am doing wrong please. I am new to the password_verify as i have just been told to use it instead of md5. (*I KNOW MY CODE CAN HAVE SQL INJECTIONS, A FRIEND IS HELPING TONIGHT TO SHOW ME HOW TO PREVENT IT*)

```
<?php
/*
*
* Copyright 2017 by Jarrod Estepp
* This script is private software and is illegal to
* use without consent from Jarrod Estepp - hello@jarrodestepp.me
*
* login_process.php
*/

include('../includes/settings.php');
include('../includes/mysql.php');

//Grab Login Info
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//verify password
$stored_pass = $conn->query("SELECT password FROM admins WHERE email = '$email'");
$password_verify = password_verify($password, $stored_pass);


$sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password_verify'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (!$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    header("location: {$website_domain}/admin/login?s=1");
} else {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header("location: {$website_domain}/admin/dashboard");
}

?>
```

If you need anything else to give me help (Any other files) i will be glad to comment them. I greatly appreciate anybody's help as i am just learning to code and this is something that has took me over 5+ hours to try to fix and still nothing.

Any answers are appreciated!

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: As stated in the post i know that its not secure. I am learning at the moment and i have a mentor that is helping me tonight to prevent SQL injection. This was just so i could get started on panels to make what i know how to do!

Comment: I appreciate the backup of my vulnerability tho!

Comment: Unless you're doing this for purely academic reasons, you really must use a framework that's already implemented this in a secure, testable way. While I do encourage learning, doing it from the ground up is an extraordinarily painful and difficult way to do it. Glad to hear you've got a mentor. Hope that works out.

Comment: My mentor is learning me to keep things secure as i build up from ground. Yes it has been difficult but i am not really a newbie. I have been editing PHP code for over a year but this is my first actual "code".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is not correct, the password_verify return a boolean (Returns TRUE if the password and hash match, or FALSE otherwise.). The password encryption use a non reversible mechanisms, in other words, its not possible decrypt the password. The password_verify method encrypt the given password and compare hash with database saved hash, if match your password is the same.

Then update your code to:

```
if (!$password_verify) {
    header("location: {$website_domain}/admin/login?s=1");
} else {
    $sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email = '$email'");
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    header("location: {$website_domain}/admin/dashboard");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to answer my question. I am checking it now!

Comment: I tried this one first and it worked! Your time to answer my question is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Now that i placed this, the session id isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is your problem

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password_verify'";
```

So password_verify() function basically returns a boolean value that is true or false, accroding to me you need something like this:-

```
if (!$password_verify) {
    header("location: {$website_domain}/admin/login?s=1");
} else {
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
   $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
   header("location: {$website_domain}/admin/dashboard");
}
```

I think this will solve the error which you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your time to help in my issue. I appreciate your answer very much! I will see if this were to work!